# How do i format a value as a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do some simple projects on my own to learn python a little better, what I am trying to do is format the the values into fields. I've managed to sort the keys in ascending order and match the keys with their respective lists.
I know why only the first word in the list gets formatted and that is because it is being treated as one string with spaces in-between, I am at a complete loss as how to proceed

It should look like this:

```
Id      name      species      age      spayed/neutered
1020    b         cat          9        yes
1022    brn       dog          10       no
1023    bren      cat          2        yes
```

This is the relevant function that will be displaying the information from the dictionary, and my progress so far.

```
cust_rec = {'1020': ['b','cat','9','yes'], '1023': ['brn','dog','10','no'], '1022': ['bren','cat','2','yes']}

def cust_disp (cust_rec):

    for key in sorted(cust_rec.keys()):
    print("{0:12s} {1:10s} {2:10s} {3:4s} {4:s}".format("ID","Name","Species","Age","Spayed/Neutered"))
    print ("{0:12s} {1:10s}".format(key, " ".join(cust_rec[key])  ) )
```

If i need to clarify anything let me know.

Comment: Why not use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the formatted data in a `list` then join the list

```
cust_rec = {
    "Id": ["name", "species", "age", "spayed/neutered"],
    '1020': ['b', 'cat', '9', 'yes'],
    '1023': ['brn', 'dog', '10', 'no'],
    '1022': ['bren', 'cat', '2', 'yes']
}

a = [
    f"{k:>15} {v[0]:>15} {v[1]:>15} {v[2]:>15} {v[3]:>15}"
    for k, v in cust_rec.items()
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("\n".join(a))
```

prints

```
         Id            name         species             age spayed/neutered
       1020               b             cat               9             yes
       1023             brn             dog              10              no
       1022            bren             cat               2             yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas would probably be a good option

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(cust_rec).T
```

Otherwise try this:

```
for key, vals in cust_rec.iteritems():
    to_print = '\t'.join(str(val) for val in vals)
    print key + '\t' + to_print
```

Comment: im going to take a look at pandas, but this did work with some manipulation: i should have specified i was using python3, so iteritems() didnt work.

but this did work so thank you very much

Comment: Oh, I didn't know iteritems() didn't work with python 3, my bad. Edited post to get you started with pandas

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is making a string of a list with one white space between elements. what you want to do is make all the string same length with white spaces filling out the rest of the desired length, and then join them in one string. you can do so with ljust string method.

```
def cust_disp(cust_rec):
    columns = ["ID", "Name", "Species", "Age", "Spayed/Neutered"]
    formated_columns = "".join([column.ljust(10, " ") for column in columns])
    print(formated_columns)
    for key in sorted(cust_rec.keys()):
        print("{0:10s}{1}".format(
            key, "".join([field.ljust(10, " ") for field in cust_rec[key]])))
```